# Unable to configure BBB with Macbook pro M1

Tags: apple-m1, beagleboneblack, beagleboard

I am new to Beaglebone Black (BBB). I was trying to connect BBB with Macbook Pro M1 but unable to do that. In network interfaces, it always shows BBB as not connected. I have tried setting it up manually. (If I select automatically DHCP, IP section and all will remain empty).

Config of IP in macbook
[image]

Below is the /etc/network/interfaces file:
[image]

I would like to tell that i am able to login in BBB by using below command
"screen /dev/tty.usb*******"
where ****** is random number which will be always different.

If anybody can help that will be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your first screenshot says that the status of the cable is unplugged.
Try to install the appropriate Network serial driver for mac OS as given in BeagleBoard.org and check your status.

[USB drivers for different operating system][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HDHh.png

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have tried all the things then I mentioned this question here. For both of the drivers it says that it does not supports current version of Mac OS and I am on MacOS Monterey 12.2.1.